# I am trying to show an input field if the "other" option is selected in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="ID_bank_selection">
    <option>BANK CENTRAL ASIA</option>
    <option>BANK MANDIRI</option>
    <option>BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA (BRI)</option>
    <option>BANK NASIONAL INDONESIA 46 (BNI 46)</option>
    <option>CIMB NIAGA BANK</option>
    <option>BANK DANAMON</option>
    <option>BANK INTERNATIONAL INDONESIA (BII)</option>
    <option>BANK PERMATA</option>
    <option>BANK MANDIRI SYARIAH</option>
    <option>BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA SYARIAH</option>
    <option name="other" id="id_other" val="1">OTHER (Add Bank Name Below)</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br>
<label>Bank Name:</label>
<input class="hide-vn" type="text" name="nameofbank" id="nameofbanktext" size="20" value="" placeholder="Other Bank Name">

CSS:
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nameOfBank = $('#nameofbanktext').addClass('hidden');
    var idBank = $('#ID_bank_selection');
    var otherOption = $("#ID_bank_selection option[name='other']");


    idBank.change(function(){
        if($('option:selected').val() == '1'){
            nameofBank.removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });    
});
```

I've tried many solutions of related questions but none of them have worked. Please help me as I need to get this taken care of as soon as possible. Here is a link to a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3y8q40q/

Comment: The property name on `<option name="other" value="1">` should be `value` not `val`. http://jsfiddle.net/k3y8q40q/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFIDDLE DEMO => http://jsfiddle.net/t341vdL3/1/

2 changes are required to make your functionality work

1. HTML - use `value` instead of `val`

   `<option name="other" id="id_other" value="1">OTHER (Add Bank Name Below)</option>`
2. Javascript

   ```
   var nameOfBank = $('#nameofbanktext').addClass('hidden');
   var idBank = $('#ID_bank_selection');
   var otherOption = $("#ID_bank_selection option[name='other']");    

   idBank.change(function(){
       var selectedValue = $(this).val(); //use $(this)

       if(selectedValue == 1){
           nameOfBank.removeClass('hidden'); //typo here 'O' caps
       }
   });
   ```

Also, I suggest you to prepend jquery selector variables with `$`.

For example: `var $idBank = $('#ID_bank_selection');` Doing this, you'll know which variable is a jquery selector and which one is not.

Comment: thank you! It worked great now that I have value instead of val.

Comment: @BrentNicolet - glad to help. please upvote all helpful answers and accept one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

someting like:

```
idBank.on("change", function(){
        if($(this).val() == '1'){
            $("#nameofbanktext").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#nameofbanktext").hide();
        }
    });
```

HERE complete solution:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/tirso/9x0f1L32/)

Answer (score 0):

First on the html  you are setting the value 1 to the property "val" that doesn't exist, you need to use "value".
Additionally, the name of the var "nameOfBank" is wrong inside the If statement, with lower case "o".

so your code should be:

```
<select id="ID_bank_selection">
    <option>BANK CENTRAL ASIA</option>
    <option>BANK MANDIRI</option>
    <option>BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA (BRI)</option>
    <option>BANK NASIONAL INDONESIA 46 (BNI 46)</option>
    <option>CIMB NIAGA BANK</option>
    <option>BANK DANAMON</option>
    <option>BANK INTERNATIONAL INDONESIA (BII)</option>
    <option>BANK PERMATA</option>
    <option>BANK MANDIRI SYARIAH</option>
    <option>BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA SYARIAH</option>
    <option name="other" id="id_other" value="1">OTHER (Add Bank Name Below)</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br>
<label>Bank Name:</label>
<input class="hide-vn" type="text" name="nameofbank" id="nameofbanktext" size="20" value="" placeholder="Other Bank Name">

CSS:
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nameOfBank = $('#nameofbanktext').addClass('hidden');
    var idBank = $('#ID_bank_selection');
    var otherOption = $("#ID_bank_selection option[name='other']");


    idBank.change(function(){
        if($('option:selected').val() == '1'){
            nameOfBank.removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nameofbanktext').hide();
var idBank = $('#ID_bank_selection');
var otherOption = $("#ID_bank_selection option[name='other']");
idBank.change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1){
         $('#nameofbanktext').show();
    }
   else
   {
       $('#nameofbanktext').hide();
   }                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr('name')` instead of `val()`, or use `value` as your attribute name but any way, you've misspeled the name of variable where you did store your `input` object - 
`nameOfBank` instead of `nameofBank` in your fiddle

```
 idBank.change(function(){
    if($('option:selected').attr('name') == 'other'){
        nameOfBank.removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

or

```
idBank.change(function(){
    if($('option:selected').val() == '1'){
        nameOfBank.removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle name](http://jsfiddle.net/k3y8q40q/8/)

[Fiddle val()](http://jsfiddle.net/k3y8q40q/10/)